# How can I silently decline a meeting?

Tags: vba, outlook

I've currently got a script that I tie to a rule so that I can auto-decline meeting requests with certain subjects:

```
Sub AutoDeclineMeetings(oRequest As MeetingItem)

If oRequest.MessageClass <> "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
  Exit Sub
End If

Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
Set oAppt = oRequest.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)

Dim oResponse
 Set oResponse = oAppt.Respond(olMeetingDeclined, True)
 oResponse.Send

End Sub
```

However, this sends a response back to the meeting organizer, which unnecessarily spams them, since they don't care if I attend or not.

How can I change this code so that the meeting does not show up in my calendar and so that no response is sent? I've tried simply calling both `oAppt.Delete` and `oRequest.Delete`, but this does not remove the item from my calendar.

Effectively, what I'm looking for is the equivalent of manually selecting **Decline -> Do Not Send a Reponse** on the meeting request.

Comment: If they don't care if you attend, why respond at all, why not just delete the request?

Comment: @JoeEnos I believe I've tried both deleting the AppointmentItem (which seemed to have no effect) and the Request (which deleted the actual email request, but left the meeting in my Calendar), but I'll test and double-check.

Comment: I just double-checked (by calling both `oAppt.Delete` and `oRequest.Delete`) and the item was still in my Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `oResponse.Send`, try `oResponse.Close(olDiscard)`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to actually save the fact that I've declined, as it still appears in my calendar and says "This meeting has not been accepted." when I hover over it. I also tried `oResponse.Close(olSave)`, which did not work either.

Comment: I may have other issues going on, since now my previous script which sent the decline response doesn't seem to be working either. So maybe this does work and I managed to do something that prevents it from even executing. I cannot confirm or deny this answer right now. Can anyone else?

Comment: @Sterno Is the same code from your question the code that's not working?  Or have you modified it since so that it no longer works?  If so, can you please update the question with the current version of your script?

Comment: The exact same code as pasted in my question is no longer working for me, though it was on Friday. It's making me wonder if I somehow screwed up my Rule that runs the script (though I really don't see how).

Comment: Try making sure you haven't changed your security settings so that Macros are no longer enabled.  The only thing I could imagine is that somehow the code is just not running at all, as opposed to being incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the response rather than sending it:

`oResponse.Delete` instead of `oResponse.Send`

```
Sub DeclineSelected()
    Dim Session As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim currentExplorer As Explorer
    Dim Selection As Selection
    Dim currentItem As Object
    Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
    Dim oResponse

    Set currentExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set Selection = currentExplorer.Selection

    'For all items selected...
    For Each currentItem In Selection
        'If it is a meeting request...
        If currentItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
            Set oAppt = currentItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
            If oAppt.ResponseRequested Then
                Set oResponse = oAppt.Respond(olMeetingDeclined, True, False)
                oResponse.Delete
            Else
                Set oResponse = oAppt.Respond(olMeetingDeclined, True, False)
            End If
            currentItem.Delete

        'If it is a meeting cancellation...
        ElseIf currentItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Canceled" Then
            Set oAppt = currentItem.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
            If oAppt Is Nothing Then
                currentItem.Delete
            End If

    'Delete if just an email...
        ElseIf currentItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
            currentItem.Delete
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```